# BASH shell scripting using parameters

Tags: linux, bash

I am trying to create three BASH scripts to help organize my terminals and workspace on my VM.

Below are the commands that I wish to have parameterized.

1) How to rename the title of a terminal window:

```
PS1='\[\e]0;TERMINAL NAME\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

2) To change the number of workspaces:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences num-workspaces "5"
```

3) To rename the name of Workspaces:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.wm.preferences workspace-names "['IntelliJ', 'Cloud Discovery', 'Full Stack', 'Simulators', 'Misc']"
```

It's been a little while since I have done BASH scripting and I am forgetting how to run a console command via a BASH script.

My initial attempts have all failed.  Here is the code that I am written most recently:

```
#!/bin/bash
export cmd="PS1='\[\e]0;$1\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '"
echo {$cmd}

./setNewTermName MyName
```

But when I run the script as above, it is not renaming the terminal.  However, when I run the PS1 command above directly on the command like (substituting in the actual name), it works.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?

Comment: The only thing needed to change the title is to write the correct string (`\e]0;new title\a`) to the terminal. This is typically embedded in your prompt so that each time the prompt is displayed, the title is updated.

Comment: `{$cmd}` is not `${cmd}`. And quotes matter: `echo "$cmd"`. And there's no point to `export`ing a variable that you don't need subprocesses to be able to read (which is the entire *point* of `export`, as opposed to a simple assignment). Consider running code through http://shellcheck.net/ before asking questions here.

Comment: That said, if you expect your command to actually change `PS1` -- a script can't change its parent process's variables; it can only change those of itself or its children.

Comment: Not sure I follow Charles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define a local variable that will get the value of the title as an argument as under. Then you will use that local variable (title in this case) in your PS1 variable.

Then, in order to run the script, you need to "[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command))" the script in the current shell so that the variable in the script are visible to the parent shell.

```
#!/bin/bash

title=$1;

PS1='\[\e]0;${title}\a\]${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
```

So, instead of running the script as

```
./setNewTermName MyName
```

Run without the / as under. Notice the space after the period:

```
. setNewTermName MyName
```

Or as:

```
source setNewTermName MyName
```